# how to add fields to bson in MongoDB C driver

Tags: mongodb, bson

For appending to bulk write in order to update existing fields within a doc, I can't do it all in place, I need to call an append function repeatedly as data becomes available, thanks for any hints, I am clueless how to do it ?

```
void appendfn(bson_t* doc, char * name, char* value) 
{
    char *str;
    bson_t child;

    bson_append_document_begin (doc, "$set", -1, &child);
    BSON_APPEND_UTF8(&child, name, value);
    bson_append_document_end (doc, &child);

    str=bson_as_canonical_extended_json (doc, NULL);
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

bson_t doc=BSON_INITIALIZER;
appendfn(&doc,"f1","f1v") yields :
{ "$set" : { "f1" : "f1v" } }

if I call it again appendfn(&doc,"f2","f2v") :

{ "$set" : { "f1" : "f1v" }, "$set" : { "f2" : "f2v" } }

but I need :

{ "$set" : { "f1" : "f1v", "f2" : "f2v" } }

for argument's sake I could do something of the sort (from a single thread) :

```
    void appendmore(bson_t* doc, char * name, char* value) 
    {
        char *str;
        static bson_t *child=NULL;// static is only for single thread obviously, need thread local storage for multiple threads
    
        if(!child)
        {
            child=bson_new ();
            bson_append_document_begin (doc, "$set", -1, child);
        }
        if(name)
        {
            BSON_APPEND_UTF8(child, name, value);
            str=bson_as_canonical_extended_json (child, NULL);
            printf("child %s\n",str);
        }
        else
            bson_append_document_end (doc, child);
    }

appendmore(&doc,"f1","f1v");
appendmore(&doc,"f2","f2v");
appendmore(&doc,NULL,NULL);
```

there must be a way to continue adding fields in an "opened" child ? i.e. to reopen it somehow ?

another thing I can't understand, with latest 1.19 c driver, child seems cannot be allocated with new, it must be static because it gets flagged as BSON_FLAG_NO_FREE

to better frame the question in terms of original BSON documentation : http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.6/tutorial.html

name : {
first : "Grace",
last : "Hopper"
},

how to continue appending fields within the doc "name" say with multiple bson_append_document_begin ? how to specify append to **existing** key "name",
it could be the "dot" notation but how in terms of mongo C lib ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes down to trying to append new `child` documents to the outer `doc`.

> there must be a way to continue adding fields in an "opened" child

Yes, append key/values to the `child` rather than opening new bson_t children on the main `doc`

Hold onto a reference to the `child` and add anything you want to it

Once you have the `child`, simply append your utf8 (or any other) key/values to the `child` rather than continuing to open new `child`ren on the `doc`.

Once you're done appending to `child`, only then can you call `bson_append_document_end` on the `child`

```c
static
void append_more(bson_t * child, const char * key, const char * value){
    // This doesn't really need to be a function, but to match the example
    if (key) {
        BSON_APPEND_UTF8(child, key, value);
    }
}

static
void appending_test(){
    bson_t doc=BSON_INITIALIZER;
    bson_t child;
    // prepare the child outside of the append function
    bson_append_document_begin (&doc, "$set", -1, &child);


    // Example appended UTF8 to the outer doc, rather than to the child
    BSON_APPEND_UTF8(&child, "k1", "v1");  // Append directly
    // Or wrap the call in a function
    append_more(&child, "k2", "v2"); //append_more created above
    append_more(&child, "k3", "v3"); //append_more created above

    // don't call this until you're done appending
    bson_append_document_end(&doc, &child);

    printf("%s\n", bson_as_canonical_extended_json(&doc, NULL));
}
```

prints

```
    { "$set" : { "k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2", "k3" : "v3" } }
```

For your second specific example,

```c
static
void name_test(){
    bson_t doc=BSON_INITIALIZER;
    bson_t name_field;
    // prepare the child outside of the append function
    bson_append_document_begin (&doc, "name", -1, &name_field);

    append_more(&name_field, "first", "Grace"); //append_more created above
    append_more(&name_field, "last", "Hopper"); //append_more created above

    // don't call this until you're done appending
    bson_append_document_end(&doc, &name_field);

    printf("%s\n", bson_as_canonical_extended_json(&doc, NULL));
}
```

prints

```
{ "name" : { "first" : "Grace", "last" : "Hopper" } }
```

Finally, your question about bson_new still works in 1.19

Somewhere in your program you need to use `bson_new` to put your document on the heap.  At the end of your program, use `bson_destroy` to clean it up.  You are probably running into errors because you're `bson_new`ing to generate your `child`ren when you shouldn't

```c
static
void heap_test(){
    // Using a bson pointer to heap rather than struct on stack
    bson_t * doc = bson_new();
    bson_t * name_field = bson_new();

    bson_append_document_begin (doc, "name", -1, name_field);
    // -------------------------^ not a reference anymore

    append_more(name_field, "first", "Grace"); //append_more created above
    append_more(name_field, "last", "Hopper"); //append_more created above
    // ---------^ not a reference anymore

    // don't call this until you're done appending
    bson_append_document_end(doc, name_field);
    // ----------------------^ not a reference anymore

    printf("%s\n", bson_as_canonical_extended_json(doc, NULL));
    // ---------------------------------------------------^ not a reference anymore


    // Must destroy documents from the heap
    bson_destroy(name_field);
    bson_destroy(doc);
}
```

prints

```
{ "name" : { "first" : "Grace", "last" : "Hopper" } }
```

*Stack overflow defaults to a ridiculously over-protective license for these answers. To the extent allowed, I place all code and words within this answer into the public domain.  Where public domain is not allowed or recognized, the code and words is licensed under the same license as libbson itself.*

Comment: hmm, can you call multiple times bson_append_document_begin/end on the same parent ? let's say "Grace" "Hopper", "Grace1" "Hopper1", "Grace2" "Hopper2" ...

Comment: yes, that's exactly what you did in the question where you got two $set keys with their own data in it.

Comment: hmm, from my understanding, you cannot re insert a sub tree in the parent, which somehow stays "opened" in some sort of non reinsertable state ? I hope I am mistaken ? I think it's due to it being binary structs and you need to "physically" shift binary chunks around ?

Comment: hmm also take notice in the official example how come they only insert the "Grace Hopper" sub tree once and once only

Comment: you asked if you can, yes you can.  You should not because it will lead to parsing errors in divers that can't handle duplicate keys in a BSON document.  But you can do it.

Comment: obviously I meant non duplicate keys such as "Grace" "Grace1" "Grace2" ...

Comment: { "$set" : { "baz" : { "$numberInt" : "1" } }, "$set" : { "baz" : { "$numberInt" : "1" } } } I need a way with root key "$set" "baz" once only ...

Comment: there's 3 examples in the answer that explain how to set a key and append new elements to the child document without creating a new child document.  Can you edit your question with exactly what input you intend to use and exactly what output you expect to see and exactly what steps you've tried?